# JS смена маски тел input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста с кодом.
Как сделать изменение маски телефона в поле input при смене option в selct

Мой код:

```js
$('select#shipping_address_country[name="shipping_address[country]"]').on('change', function() {
  $('.co-input-field.js-input-field#client_phone[type="tel"]').val($(this).val());
}).change();


$(function(){
  $("#client_phone").mask("+34(999) 999-9999");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" style="padding-top:20px">

<input class="co-input-field js-input-field" type="tel" id="client_phone" name="client[phone]" value="">

<select class="co-input-field js-input-field" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" id="shipping_address_country" name="shipping_address[country]">
  <option value="PT" selected="selected">Portugal</option>
  <option value="ES">Spain</option>
</select>
```

Так-же в jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/synapse3/0rc3x8pq/25/

сейчас выводится значение value, а нужно подставлять для Espain и Portugal - свои маски.

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#shipping_address_country').on('change', function() {
  let phone = $("#client_phone"), 
        mask = '';
  switch($(this).val()) {
    case 'PT':
        mask = "+20(999) 999-9999";
      break;
    case 'ES':
        mask = "+31(999) 999-9999";
      break;
    default:
        mask = "+75(999) 999-9999";
      break;
  }
  phone.mask(mask);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<div class="" style="padding-top:20px">

<input class="co-input-field js-input-field" type="text" id="client_phone" name="client[phone]" value="">

<select class="co-input-field js-input-field" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" id="shipping_address_country" name="shipping_address[country]">
  <option value="PT" selected="selected">Portugal</option>
  <option value="ES">Spain</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: нет, чет не работает